Implementing a nonlinear controller for a quadrotor aircraft
I was trying to implement a nonlinear controller based on nested saturation technique for a quadrotor UAV as part of an college assignment. The controller design is given in detail in this paper Nonlinear control for systems with bounded inputs: Real-time embedded control applied to UAVs. This is the MATLAB code:
    % Nonlinear Controller for UAV with Nested Saturation Technique
    % Implements quadrotor control based on real-time embedded nonlinear control
    
    clear; clc; close all;
    
    %% Parameters of the UAV
    m = 1;                 % Mass of the UAV [kg]
    g = 9.81;              % Gravity [m/s^2]
    I_x = 5e-3;            % Inertia along x-axis [kg*m^2]
    I_y = 5e-3;            % Inertia along y-axis [kg*m^2]
    Iz = 9e-3;             % Inertia along z-axis [kg*m^2]
    I_r = 4e-5;            % Rotor inertia [kg*m^2]
    l = 0.22;              % Arm length [m]
    mu = 3e-6;             % Thrust coefficient
    kappa = 1.5e-7;        % Drag coefficient
    
    %% Controller Parameters
    r1 = 3;  % Saturation limits for altitude control
    r2 = 1.4;  % Saturation limits for yaw control
    psi1 = 1.5; % Saturation for yaw rate
    psi2 = 0.7; % Saturation for yaw angle
    
    % Pitch and roll controller saturation and gains
    a_theta = 1.7; b_theta = 0.82; c_theta = 0.36; d_theta = 0.16;
    a_phi = 1.7; b_phi = 0.82; c_phi = 0.4; d_phi = 0.18;
    
    % Gains for yaw control
    k_r1 = 1; k_r2 = 2;
    k_psi1 = 1; k_psi2 = 2;
    
    % Nested saturation gains for theta and phi (pitch and roll)
    k1_theta = 0.2; k2_theta = 0.5; k3_theta = 0.5; k4_theta = 1.8;
    k1_phi = 0.5; k2_phi = 0.5; k3_phi = 0.5; k4_phi = 1;
    
    %% Initial conditions (position and orientation)
    x0 = 2; y0 = -3; z0 = 0; % Initial position [m]
    phi0 = -0.7; theta0 = 0.8; psi0 = 0; % Initial orientation [rad]
    xd = 0; yd = 0; zd = 1; % Desired position [m]
    psi_d = 1;              % Desired yaw angle [rad]
    
    %% Time setup
    T = 20;                 % Simulation time [s]
    dt = 0.01;              % Time step [s]
    time = 0:dt:T;
    n = length(time);
    
    %% State Vector Initialization
    state = [x0; y0; z0; phi0; theta0; psi0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0]; % [x, y, z, phi, theta, psi, x_dot, y_dot, z_dot, phi_dot, theta_dot, psi_dot]
    
    % Pre-allocate arrays for storing results
    pos_data = zeros(n, 3);    % [x, y, z]
    orient_data = zeros(n, 3); % [phi, theta, psi]
    control_inputs = zeros(n, 4); % [u, tau_phi, tau_theta, tau_psi]
    
    %% Simulation Loop
    for i = 1:n
        % Extract the state variables
        x = state(1); y = state(2); z = state(3);
        phi = state(4); theta = state(5); psi = state(6);
        x_dot = state(7); y_dot = state(8); z_dot = state(9);
        phi_dot = state(10); theta_dot = state(11); psi_dot = state(12);
        
        %% Altitude control (z)
        r = -nested_saturation(k_r1*z_dot + nested_saturation(k_r2*z_dot + k_r1*k_r2*(z-zd), r2), r1);
        u = (m*r + m*g) / (cos(theta) * cos(phi)); % Thrust for altitude
        
       %% Yaw control (psi)
    tau_psi = -nested_saturation(k_psi1*psi_dot + nested_saturation(k_psi2*psi_dot + k_psi1*k_psi2*(psi - psi_d), psi2), psi1);
        
     %% Pitch and Roll Control
    % Roll (phi) - Using the new nested saturation formula
    tau_phi = -nested_saturation(k1_phi*phi_dot + ...
        nested_saturation(k2_phi*(phi_dot + k1_phi*phi) + ...
        nested_saturation(k3_phi*(phi_dot + (k1_phi + k2_phi)*phi + k2_phi*k1_phi*y_dot/g) + ...
        nested_saturation(k4_phi*(phi_dot + (k1_phi + k2_phi + k3_phi)*phi + ...
        (k2_phi*k1_phi + k3_phi*k1_phi + k3_phi*k2_phi)*y_dot/g + ...
        k1_phi*k2_phi*k3_phi*y/g), d_phi), c_phi), b_phi), a_phi);
    
    % Pitch (theta) - Using the new nested saturation formula
    tau_theta = -nested_saturation(k1_theta*theta_dot + ...
        nested_saturation(k2_theta*(theta_dot + k1_theta*theta) + ...
        nested_saturation(k3_theta*(theta_dot + (k1_theta + k2_theta)*theta - k2_theta*k1_theta*x_dot/g) + ...
        nested_saturation(k4_theta*(theta_dot + (k1_theta + k2_theta + k3_theta)*theta - ...
        (k2_theta*k1_theta + k3_theta*k1_theta + k3_theta*k2_theta)*x_dot/g - ...
        k3_theta*k2_theta*k1_theta*x/g), d_theta), c_theta), b_theta), a_theta);
        % Control torques
        tau = [tau_phi; tau_theta; tau_psi]; 
        
        %% Dynamics Update
        % Position dynamics
        F = [0; 0; u]; % Thrust force in the z-direction
        acc = (F / m) - [0; 0; g]; % Net acceleration
        state(1:3) = state(1:3) + state(7:9) * dt; % Update position
        state(7:9) = state(7:9) + acc * dt;        % Update velocity
    
        % Orientation dynamics
        omega = [phi_dot; theta_dot; psi_dot];
        I = diag([I_x, I_y, Iz]); % Inertia matrix
        I_inv = inv(I); % Inverse of inertia matrix
        omega_dot = I_inv * (tau - cross(omega, I * omega)); % Angular velocity update
        state(4:6) = state(4:6) + state(10:12) * dt; % Update orientation (phi, theta, psi)
        state(10:12) = state(10:12) + omega_dot * dt; % Update angular velocities
        
        %% Store data for plotting
        pos_data(i, :) = state(1:3);    % Store position [x, y, z]
        orient_data(i, :) = state(4:6); % Store orientation [phi, theta, psi]
        control_inputs(i, :) = [u, tau_phi, tau_theta, tau_psi]; % Store control inputs
    end
    
    %% Plotting Results
    
    % 1. Position (x, y, z)
    figure;
    subplot(3,1,1);
    plot(time, pos_data(:,1), 'r', 'LineWidth', 1.5);
    xlabel('Time [s]'); ylabel('x [m]');
    title('Position in x-direction');
    grid on;
    
    subplot(3,1,2);
    plot(time, pos_data(:,2), 'g', 'LineWidth', 1.5);
    xlabel('Time [s]'); ylabel('y [m]');
    title('Position in y-direction');
    grid on;
    
    subplot(3,1,3);
    plot(time, pos_data(:,3), 'b', 'LineWidth', 1.5);
    xlabel('Time [s]'); ylabel('z [m]');
    title('Position in z-direction');
    grid on;
    
    % 2. Orientation (phi, theta, psi)
    figure;
    subplot(3,1,1);
    plot(time, orient_data(:,1), 'r', 'LineWidth', 1.5);
    xlabel('Time [s]'); ylabel('\phi [rad]');
    title('Roll Angle \phi');
    grid on;
    
    subplot(3,1,2);
    plot(time, orient_data(:,2), 'g', 'LineWidth', 1.5);
    xlabel('Time [s]'); ylabel('\theta [rad]');
    title('Pitch Angle \theta');
    grid on;
    
    subplot(3,1,3);
    plot(time, orient_data(:,3), 'b', 'LineWidth', 1.5);
    xlabel('Time [s]'); ylabel('\psi [rad]');
    title('Yaw Angle \psi');
    grid on;
    
    % 3. Control Inputs (u, tau_phi, tau_theta, tau_psi)
    figure;
    subplot(4,1,1);
    plot(time, control_inputs(:,1), 'b', 'LineWidth', 1.5);
    xlabel('Time [s]'); ylabel('u [N]');
    title('Vertical Thrust u');
    grid on;
    
    subplot(4,1,2);
    plot(time, control_inputs(:,2), 'r', 'LineWidth', 1.5);
    xlabel('Time [s]'); ylabel('\tau_\phi [Nm]');
    title('Roll Torque \tau_\phi');
    grid on;
    
    subplot(4,1,3);
    plot(time, control_inputs(:,3), 'g', 'LineWidth', 1.5);
    xlabel('Time [s]'); ylabel('\tau_\theta [Nm]');
    title('Pitch Torque \tau_\theta');
    grid on;
    
    subplot(4,1,4);
    plot(time, control_inputs(:,4), 'm', 'LineWidth', 1.5);
    xlabel('Time [s]'); ylabel('\tau_\psi [Nm]');
    title('Yaw Torque \tau_\psi');
    grid on;
    
    %% Nested Saturation Function (Helper Function)
    function sat_val = nested_saturation(value, sat_level)
        % Nested saturation function to limit values within bounded levels
        sat_val = sign(value) * min(abs(value), sat_level);
    end

The code runs without any errors but the outputs that I get in the form of plots of position and orientation of the quadrotor are far from correct:


As it is visible in the images, neither the position or the orientation variables are correct. The z value explodes while the x and y values are unchanged from their initial states. All three orientation Euler angles oscillate rapidly which is not desirable. I am stuck. I think I have correctly entered all the expressions correctly but maybe there is something fundamentally wrong in my understanding of the paper or the implementation that I have done. It would be really helpful if someone could point out any mistakes.

Is kappa used for both the blades and the vehicle?

They are for the rotors

I suggest sensitivity tests using 10% on each variable.  This would be impractical changing one variable at a time with multiple outputs changing so the solution is to do multi variable sensitivity tests, using the Taguchi method or the evolution method using a spreadsheet to determine the results of individual contributions to output error to find the source of your non-linear errors and drift.
Check for intermediate variable saturation or overflow.
Keep in mind motor torque drops with magnetic field strength, which drops with rising temperatures and is also non-linear, so motor thermal sensing will improve that. Also torque reduces with battery voltage and ESR rises sharply below 10% SOC.
https://www.google.com/search?q=taguchi%20evolution%20comparison&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8
